# What class are you studying?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference, semantics

It  is  a  tendency among  teachers  of  English  in India  to  ask  and  teach  sentences  of  this  kind  in the  class.

> **What  class  are  you  studying?**
>
> **Inwhich  class  are  you studying?**
>
> **What  class  are  you  in?**
>
> **Which class  are  you  in?**

In India  the  pupils  are  promoted  from class  to  class  every  year. They  are  promoted  from  first  class  to  tenth  class  year after year.   some  call  it  standard  Nobody  call  it  grades.  I  have   a class  now  means  I  have  an  English  class  now  though.

Are  the  above  expressions   used  by  the  native  speakers and  considered  correct  and  idiomatic?.  If  none  of  them  is  correct, What  is  the  correct  and  idiomatic expression used  by  the  native speakers?

Your  answer  will  help  many  teachers  of  English in India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class** here is taken to mean a particular group, year or level of students.

So your first example **What class are you studying** does not work. It would be meaningful if you said that you were interested in beetles and someone asked you:**What class (of beetles) are you studying.** This is clearly not your intention.

The other three examples are all possible but are more or less likely in different contexts.

**In which class are you studying?** is likely to be understood as **in which classroom** are you studying. It is not idiomatic and overly formal if you mean **what class....**.

**What class are you in?** is perfectly idiomatic and most likely if someone wanted to know your subject or what year you were in. A typical answer might be: I'm in **the physics/maths/English class** or **I'm in the 5th/6th/7th class**.

**Which class are you in?** is also quite possible but more appropriate in choosing between two or three named classes, as in: **I have seen you in both the English class/6th class and the French class/7th class. Which class are you (actually) in?**

Comment: @ Ronald Sole. Here  we  call  6th  class, 7th  class and  Tenth  class.The  expected  answer  is  I  am  in Class  7th( It  is  not   room. some  call  it  7th  standard. Is  it  correct  to   question  what  class  are  you  in?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Answer would be: **I'm in Class 7** or **I'm in (the) 7th class.**

Comment: @ Ronald  Sole.Could  you  please  edit  your  answer  a bit  since  I have  edited  my question.

Comment: I'll add a line but I think that Ksenia13's answer (which I have upvoted) covers the ground adequately, whether you are talking about **class** or **grade**.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your comment on Ronald Soles's post that your intended question is not about the specific subject being taken (i.e. French class or Math class), but about the level of schooling you are in, corresponding to how old you are and how long you have been in school.

A quick Google search has confirmed that the Indian school system refers to its levels of schooling as "classes", meaning one can be in 2nd class, 6th class, 8th class, etc.

In Canada and the USA, we call these grades, not classes. Here, a "class" refers to the subject you are taking, like math or science or history. In Canada/USA, you start school at age 3 or 4 in what is called kindergarten or primary school. Then at age 6 you enter "grade 1" or "first grade", and each subsequent year after that you move up a grade level until grade 12 ("12th grade"), which is the last year before university. "7th grade" or "grade 7" corresponds to the year of school when a student is 11-12 years old. This is therefore the same as "class 7" in India.

Additionally, in the UK they call these "years" or "forms", as in "Year 7" or "6th form". So as you can see, there are many different words for one's current educational level depending on which country you are talking about. Regardless, the format of the English phrasing is the same.

So, the way to ask this question would be:

> "Which grade are you in?" or "What grade are you in?"

of which, the second is more common and idiomatic than the first, and to which the answer would be

> "I am in 7th grade."

So, if you are talking about your educational class level in India, you would say "What class are you in?"

You could also say, "In which grade/class/year are you?", which is technically grammatically correct but not the common way to phrase it.

Comment: I have got the notable question badge. But I was downvoted twice. So the moderators have been impartial to me right from the beginning because I question their undemocratic and pedantic ways. This site is imperialistic. Some of the so called expert grammarians are very haughty  and feel as though they have the monoply of English